# print string and int and time without quotes in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have four variables:-

```
measure = 'domain.bandwidth' (string type)
time = datetime.datetime.now() (datetime type)
players_count = 50 (int type)
bandwidth = 3672782 (int type)
```

Now I want to print on CLI exactly like below:-

```
domain.bandwidth,time=2020-08-28 17:55:55.567057,players_count=50,bandwidth=3672782
```

There should be no quotes or anything the output has to be strictly like above.

I am using python 2.7 and trying to avoid use of any external libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use the following formatted printing:

```
import datetime

measure = 'domain.bandwidth'
time = datetime.datetime.now()
players_count = 50
bandwidth = 3672782

print('%s,time=%s,players_count=%s,bandwidth=%s'
        % (measure, time.strftime('%Y-%M-%d %H:%I:%S.%f'), players_count, bandwidth))
```

Comment: Hey @Ivan how can i update this to give the out like               domain.bandwidth time=2020-20-2316:04:53.429618,last_minute_total_players=286,last_minute_outgoing_bandwidth_bytes=3999073  basically a blank space between domain.bandwidth and time

Comment: Hi @abhi, simply put a space there. Like `'%s, time=%s...'`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering Python **2.x**:

One way could be to cast all of them to type `str` and then concatenate using `,`:

```
import datetime
measure = 'domain.bandwidth' # (string type)
time = str(datetime.datetime.now()) # (datetime type)
players_count = str(50) # (int type)
bandwidth = str(3672782)  # (int type)
x = measure + "," + time + "," + players_count + "," + bandwidth
print(x)
```

OUTPUT:

```
domain.bandwidth,2020-08-29 00:12:49.396197,50,3672782
```

**EDIT**:

Using `join()`:

```
print(",".join([measure, time, players_count, bandwidth]))
```

**EDIT 2**:

Using `format()`:

```
print("{0},{1},{2},{3}".format(measure,time,players_count,bandwidth))
```

Comment: The output shoudl be domain.bandwidth,time=2020-08-28 17:55:55.567057,players_count=50,bandwidth=3672782